# Is it possible to use the same Resource Style in multiple buttons and change the background image individually on a IsMouseOver event in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

The following code effectively displays an image as the background for a button and changes the image on a `isMouseOver` event. What I would like to be able to do is use the same style for multiple buttons but be able to change the background image (`ImageBrush`) individually for each button since each one will use a different image.

Is it possible to use the same Resource Style in multiple buttons and change the background image individually on an `IsMouseOver` or do I need separate styles for each one?

### Style

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MainMenuButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                        <Border x:Name="button" CornerRadius="12" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">

                            <TextBlock  Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                                <Setter TargetName="button"  Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyProject;component/Design/Images/my-image.png" Stretch="None"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="button"  Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource MyCustomColor}"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="button" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

### Use

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton"
    Style="{StaticResource MainMenuButtonTemplate}" 
    Margin="0,50,0,0" 
    Width="auto" 
    Height="60" 
    Command="{Binding FindrViewCommand}" 
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
    Foreground="White" >
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Design/Images/my-hover-image.png" Stretch="None"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: Another answer written by me, which shows attached DP using for IsMouseOver trigger: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45909174/1506454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Button class only contains one Dependency Property (DP) for Background, there is no DP for IsMouseOver background.

You have multiple choices, here's a few :

**1) Create an Attached Property named IsMouseOverBackground of type Brush and bind to it in your Style.**

C#

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ButtonHelper
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseOverBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsMouseOverBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(ButtonHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static Brush GetIsMouseOverBackground(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Brush)obj.GetValue(IsMouseOverBackgroundProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsMouseOverBackground(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsMouseOverBackgroundProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<!-- ... -->
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="button" Property="Background" Value="{Binding (local:ButtonHelper.IsMouseOverBackground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
</Trigger>
<!-- ... -->
```

Note the use of parentheses in the Binding, that is needed when binding to an Attached Property.

**2) Create a IsMouseOverButton class that inherits from Button, add a DP called IsMouseOverBackground of type Brush and bind to it in your Style.**

C#

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class IsMouseOverButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseOverBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsMouseOverBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(IsMouseOverButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public Brush IsMouseOverBackground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(IsMouseOverBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsMouseOverBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:IsMouseOverButton}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IsMouseOverButton}">

                    <Border x:Name="button" CornerRadius="12" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">

                        <TextBlock  Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="button" Property="Background" Value="{Binding IsMouseOverBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Trigger>
<!-- ... -->

<local:IsMouseOverButton x:Name="MyButton"
                         Style="{StaticResource MainMenuButtonTemplate}" 
                         Margin="0,50,0,0" 
                         Width="auto" 
                         Height="60" 
                         Command="{Binding FindrViewCommand}"
                         BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                         Foreground="White">
    <local:IsMouseOverButton.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" Stretch="None"/>
    </local:IsMouseOverButton.Background>
    <local:IsMouseOverButton.IsMouseOverBackground>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="https://dummyimage.com/600x401/000/fff" Stretch="None"/>
    </local:IsMouseOverButton.IsMouseOverBackground>
</local:IsMouseOverButton>
```

**3) Use the Tag property of your Button to store the IsMouseOver background and bind to it in your Style. I'm not a fan of using Tag property as it's unclear why Tag property is used when another developer reads your code.**

Comment: there is one more option: `{DynamicResource }` for IsMouseOverBackground (see my linked Possible Duplicate)