# WPF: ControlTemplate and DataTemplate based on variable data context member

Tags: wpf

Currently I have the following two buttons in my xaml, which have different bindings to corresponding ViewModel's properties for the command handling, for the background color based on the state of the button (if active/toggled it has one color and when inactive/untoggled it has different color). And each button has its own set of viewmodel side properties for command, state and colors.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label1}"
            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Button1ClickCommand}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsButton1Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Button1_PressedColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsButton1Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Button1_ReleasedColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label2}"
            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Button2ClickCommand}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsButton2Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Button2_PressedColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsButton2Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Button2_ReleasedColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

I was planning to come up with a ControlTemplate and a DataTemplate (for the Control.ContentTemplate) to have only one declaration of a button with all sort of dynamic bindings, so when later I define two buttons based on the same template I can tell under the hood what datacontext properties to bind with. I know that on the viewmodel side I have to collect all one button related properties into one class and in the main datacontext I can have two objects of that class and each button will refer to one of them. So if my view model currently has the following properties (for simplicity get/set-s have short representations)

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand Button1ClickCommand { get; set; }
    public bool IsButton1Active { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Button1_PressedColor { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Button1_ReleasedColor { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand Button2ClickCommand { get; set; }
    public bool IsButton2Active { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Button2_PressedColor { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Button2_ReleasedColor { get; set; }
}
```

then after wrapping them into a class in the view model I can have two properties

```
class MyButton
{
    public DelegateCommand ButtonClickCommand { get; set; }
    public bool IsButtonActive { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Button_PressedColor { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Button_ReleasedColor { get; set; }
}

class MyViewModel
{
    public MyButton Button1 { get; set; }
    public MyButton Button2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then on the xaml side instead of DataContext.FORMER_PROPERTY_NAME I will address them as DataConext.Button1.PROPERTY_NAME.

So my question is how on the xaml side to implement ControlTemplate with the underlying DataTemplate to have only one template implementation and later have my buttons declared based on the template and pass the related datacontext button properties. Something like the following maybe (I know this is like dummy prototype, won't work):

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label1}" 
            Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate}" 
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonContentTemplate}" Path=DataContext.MyButton1 />
    <Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label2}" 
            Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate}" 
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonContentTemplate}" Path=DataContext.MyButton2 />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: if you use ToogleButton which has IsChecked dependency property, you won't need IsButtonActive property. as for brushes, you should keep them in the view, [see how in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907635/create-custom-binding-property-for-window-resources-style). everything can be done in Template, without changing ContentTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a `Button` style that binds to the properties of a `MyButton`:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Button_ReleasedColor}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsButtonActive}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Button_PressedColor}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

...and apply it to both buttons like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label1}" 
            Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" 
            DataContext="{Binding MyButton1}" />
    <Button Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Label2}" 
            Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" 
            DataContext="{Binding MyButton2}" />
</StackPanel>
```